# running multiple PHP versions in parallel

Tags: linux, php

This question has been on my mind for quite some time. Although I don't really expect a solution, maybe someone can at least tell me why.

I've been running multiple PHP versions in parallel with `mod_fcgid` on webservers for a long time. Unfortunately I always had to compile all but one (the "system version") of them myself. I can do that, no problem. I only wonder why there are no PHP packages from "trusted" sources that can be installed alongside each other. I think running PHP as cgi is quite common these days, so having distinct paths for different PHP versions would seem obvious to me. I can see why big vendors (red hat, debian) won't do that, but why don't repositories like dotdeb (debian) or ius (centos) package their PHP versions this way?

Comment: I came here to ask a similar question tonight. I'm increasingly needing to keep some sites on older versions of PHP while running others on 5.5+, and it's a pain to compile all bar one (I use Ubuntu). We can't be the only ones with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Repositories always contain the latest versions for security reasons. That's the short answer really. There are exceptions to every rule of course since there can be multiple "stable" versions of a given software, but usually there's just one because it would be too cumbersome to manage multiple versions.

Besides, PHP 5.5 is the version you *should* be running, and 5.4 only if you have some applications that require it. 5.3 shouldn't be used at all because it hasn't seen an update in about 6 months and is end-of-life.

Comment: ius repository for centos has php53, php54, php55 at the same time. would you forcefully upgrade a customers php version?

Comment: For shared hosting, the philosophy is a bit different and it *is* possible to run multiple versions of PHP. The repo has multiple versions, but PHP in particular doesn't have version-specific folder structures because in 99% of cases you don't need multiple versions. If it was for the sake of security of my other customers, I would certainly force an upgrade.

Comment: it's this "in 99% of cases you don't need multiple versions" i can't believe. but it's ok, maybe i'm wrong. if there was the need, people/repositories would build those packages

Comment: Well, as you pointed out some repos do have multiple versions, but PHP wasn't designed with multi-versioning in mind so the packages will overwrite each other. You could always roll your own `.rpm`s from source with the appropriate paths if you really wanted to.